# Date/time conversion error with DATEPART()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax-error, datepart

I am getting an error when I try to use the `datepart` function in a where clause.  Can someone please have a look at my syntax below and offer some suggestions?

```
DATEPART(DW,convert(date,convert(varchar(4),year)+'-'+convert(varchar(4),month)+'-
'+convert(varchar(4),day),120))
```

I am trying to create a view, and the select query works fine without the `where` clause, but when I add it it returns the following error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

Comment: That is not a syntax error, that is a error that comes from an invalid string when the conversion is executed. Does the `year`, `month` and `day` fields contain values that can be used to create valid dates?

Comment: Yes, All of the year, month and day values can be used to create valid dates.

Comment: try to put convert(date,convert(varchar(4),year)+'-'+convert(varchar(4),month)+'- '+convert(varchar(4),day),120) in a variable and print it to see the date it is creating and then put that variable in datepart function

Comment: I can add that to the field list and it is added with no errors. It shows me the day number correctly. However I do not want it in the view, but want to filter on the criteria.

Comment: Please show us an example WHERE clause that isn't working. BTW you can create a date from parts without string conversions using `DateAdd` to add onto 0 (1900-1-1) ... example for 24/3/2013 : `DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(day, 24-1,DATEADD(month, 3-1,DATEADD(year, 2013-1900, 0))))`

Comment: @MrFuzzyButton - Probably what I'd try too, especially since the date format he's chosen [isn't completely safe in SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Generally I'd probably agree with you but, as a matter of fact, the format chosen is [safe to use with the data type chosen](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11441).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PRINT   DATEPART(DW, 
    CONVERT( DATE, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(getdate()) 
        + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), MONTH(getdate())) 
        + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DAY(getdate())), 120) ) )
```